# display div based on scrollTop position using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, scrolltop

**Overall Concept**

As I continue to scroll down the page, the css `display` property of different divs will change from `none` to `block` depending on distance scrolled.  A similar example of what I'm having trouble accomplishing can be seen [here](http://www.bagigia.com/).  As the user scrolls, the purse "rotates" which is really just image changes.  Another example is [here](http://www.nike.com/fall13-app/us/en_us/flyknit).

**Design Theory**

1. get scrollTop() number, that when reached, will change the CSS property of a div from `display:none` to `display:block`;
2. get the ID's of different divs that contain different images.
3. set each specific image to have a specific scrollTop() number, that when reached, it's display settings are turned on.

As far as I can tell, this is how it's done (I'm not a doctor though, so who knows).

**[A Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XweD/)**

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setImage(anImage, contentArea){
        $.when(contentArea == $(window).scrollTop()).then(function(){
            $(anImage).css('display', 'block');
        });
    }
    setImage('#bg1', 200);
    setImage('#bg2', 300);
    setImage('#bg3', 400);
});
```

My thought behind this code was:

When the `scrollTop()` value of `anImage`(respected div containing image) equals the `contentArea`(scrollTop() value set as the value to when display changes from none to block), then `anImage`'s CSS value would change to `display:block`.  I'm not worried about removing the previous image, because the new one has a higher z-index.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="bg1"></div>
    <div id="bg2"></div>
    <div id="bg3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{height:100%;margin:0;}        
#content{
    background:#333333;
    height:1500px;
    z-index:1;
}
#bg1{
    background:blue;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    position:fixed;
    top:200px;
    display:none;
}
#bg2{
    background:green;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:3;
    position:fixed;
    top:400px;
    display:none;
}
#bg3{
    background:red;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:4;
    position:fixed;
    top:400px;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: The code for the purse is here. Kind of interesting to browse.
http://www.bagigia.com/js/bagigia.home.rotation.js

Comment: Yeah seemed to work once you change your js to use the scroll event on the window.

Answer (score 0):

so take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6XweD/2/.

If you notice i changed the style from `display:none` to `opacity:0` so that the function `$(this).height()` works, and i did some adjusment on the `top` position of the divs.

Hope this works fine :)